# BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns null intermittently

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, runnable

I am downloading few images from my server and using them in a listview. After confirming that the images have been actually downloaded (through a service), I load them to a Bitmap object using BitmapFactory.decodeFile(). The function returns null intermittently.

If I refresh the fragment, images are loaded into bitmap properly. I've mostly observed this after first download though this is not consistent. In case even if the image is already downloaded, sometimes this is observed.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
@Override
    public void run() {

        while (!downImageFile.exists()) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // Waits for 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception", e);
            }
        }
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Image downloaded now "+downImageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        //String updateWords = updateAuto(); // make updateAuto() return a string
        imageView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(downImageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    if(bm==null){
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Buzz image is null. Size is "+downImageFile.length()+"  "+downImageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
                }
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        });
    }
```

Here are the relevant logs:

```
11-08 01:32:41.290 32245-32245/com.halobee.main D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
11-08 01:32:41.290 32245-32245/com.halobee.main V/BeaconCustomList: Buzz image is null. Size is 255458  /data/user/0/com.halobee.main/files/buzz/hbuzz_b251149098404ebeb1198a5ac03087af20161107110912.jpg
```

This can not be an OutOfMemory issue since no such logs are printed and the issue is intermittent. I printed the file size just to reconfirm its existence, and it is a valid value as well. Moreover, the issue is reproducible on some devices and not all. I'm loading the image in a separate thread and not on the main thread.

Comment: Um, that `while` loop is scary. Just because the file *exists* does not mean that the file is *written completely*. Use an event bus or something to have the service tell the UI layer when the image is downloaded and fully saved.

Comment: This line `while (!downImageFile.exists())` checks if a file exists, is there any guarantee that all the bytes of the image have been written to the file before it breaks the while loop and tries to decode it?

Comment: If this is handled asynchronously you shouldn't need to loop, because blocking isn't an issue as your not in the main thread.

Comment: @MarkKeen your suggestions seem right. I need to implement something that informs the thread that the image is downloaded completely. Apart from this, using the same function in case of already downloaded image, I've observed the same issue (although less frequently). Any pointers for this scenario?

Comment: You could use an AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> that does all the blocking calls (network calls). In the method `doInBackground` make the network call, wait for the network call to return (not a problem as it's a different thread from main) then create a file, write the response body bytes into the file, decode the file with BitmapFactory, and return the bitmap to `onPostExecute()` - note if using an AsyncTask directly with an Activity look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/2687/memory-leaks/9248/avoid-leaking-activities-with-asynctask#t=201611072151244918637

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use a library to help you with this issue such as Volley, Picaso and many other android libraries

2)Try to copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array as this may help deal with larger files

```
  // copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array
                    bm.getPixels(intArray, 0, bm.getWidth(), 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                            bm.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an external library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picassa](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to do image download, caching and displaying. Anyway, if you choose not to use one of the libraries, I suggest you create a listener on your network call or the component that gets the image and only then perform the decoding part after you broadcast the availability of the file to your Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

There may be more reasons why your bitmap returns null. Firstly make sure that you have given the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions in your manifest, as well as internet permissions. Also there are some changes from android 6 and up (SDK 23). Try to change your target SDK  in your build.gradle to 22.

Comment: If you read the OP "If I refresh the fragment, images are loaded into bitmap properly" - how could this be a permissions issue?

Comment: I've certainly given the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap.decodeFile().
```

The function returns `null` intermittently.

It will do that at big images where the bitmap would become to big for available memory.

Use smaller images.

Comment: As I already told, same images are loaded after refresh. So this is not an issue.

Comment: Why not? Meanwhile the GC can have made more free memory. Try with smaller images to see.